# No such module 'Parse' swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, import

I use parse in a swift app, I can successfully import parse into my swift files.
I get this error (No such module 'Parse') the weird thing is that this happens in only one swift file while it is working in all other swift files.
How do I get this working?

Comment: Check target of this .swift file in the attributes inspector. You may have given it the wrong target when first created it.

Comment: How can I check the target?.
Yesterday the same app ran without any problems.

Comment: in xCode in a right side of a file, there two buttons - document icon and question mark icon. You need to select document icon and follow the section "Target Membership". It should match the project name. If per say you have some pods installed, the check mark may indicate that this file is targeted somewhere else.

Comment: I have the parse pod installed, see the image I posted below for more details.
Thanks for your help so far but my problem is still not fixed.

Comment: Yes, the setup seems to be correct. My last guess is to try clean build. From information I have a can't think of other problem. Sorry.

Comment: I cleaned it up a lot of times already, thanks for the help but my problem is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this line in your Swift project?

```
import Parse
```

Comment: Sure, what kind of details can I give you?

Comment: do you have a GitHub repo?

Comment: No, sorry I don't have that.

Comment: OKay, send me plz, your project via GitHub or another VCS